# requests.post hangs and keeps on retrying in python3

Tags: python-3.x, post, python-requests

I am writing a python script for an IoT device that involves posting some data to an API.This device is communicating with some node as well on a local wireless network and runs on a 4G cellular network.

Now, if the internet connection is present, the device works as expected and posts the data. But if the device is not connected to the Internet, the **requests.post** call gets stuck for an ample amount of time when in an ideal case, it should be raising **requests.ConnectionError** exception. The following part of the script tries to post the data.

```
try:
   resp = requests.post(DATA_UPLOAD_API,json=postData,timeout=2)
except requests.ConnectionError as err:
   self.logger.info("Failed to post the data with the exception-" + str(err) + "....trying again")
   count=count+1
   pass
```

Is it somehow related to the local wireless network that it keeps on retrying to post even if it's not online? If not this, what could be the issue?

Answer (score 0):

Thats because the code is throwing an exception, not just a `ConnectionError`.

Catch the exception with this instead.

```
except requests.exceptions.ConnectionError:
    print("No")
```